# React/NextJS routing prop to a grandchild's Link component not working

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, next.js

I'm kind of stuck... and can't figure out if this is an issue with NextJS.

I have three components:

- CardsList (lists all cards - has multiple `<Card>` children)
- Card (representation of a card - has a `<Button>` child)
- Button (Displays a button in card - uses `<Link>` component)

Button component contains a nextjs/link component.

I need to pass the link to the article from the CardsList, through Card, into Button (and here into my `<Link>`'s href)...

This works perfectly if I pass the link (e.g. /mytest) directly from Card to Button... It also shows the String when I route it from CardsList, through Card into button just to print it on the screen - yes, I can see its value... but it does not work when I do this:

```
export default function Button({ text, link }) {
  return (
    <Link href={link} passHref>
      <button className="bg-transparent hover:bg-primary text-link font-semibold hover:text-white py-1 px-3 border border-link hover:border-transparent rounded self-center" >
        {text}
      </button>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

Yes, `{text}` works - also passed from the grandparent component (CardsList). But the Link component does not accept the passed prop if it was not directly sent from its direct parent component! (Yes, it works, if I pass the String only one level - but if it's passed from the CardsList (and just passed through) it will not be accepted!)

> Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Failed prop type: The prop `href`
> expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `undefined`
> instead.

And yes, I know, I could use state management, but I don't want to set up the whole state management for this - as it won't need it anywhere else.

Thank you very much in advance, guys!

Sascha

Comment: How do you pass it exactly? Please post `CardsList` and `Card` code if you can

Comment: Hi Danila, I pass it like you usually pass props. The thing is that when I look at the passed prop, the value IS THERE. So it's not undefined. But passing this into the `Link` component fails. I now fixed it by creating another String with the same content - then the Link component accepts it. See my answer posting. Thx anyways!!!

Answer (score 1):

I've "fixed it" (not proud!) by just creating another String before passing the prop to the link component.

```
export default function Button({ text, link }) {
  return (
    <Link href={`${link}`} passHref>
      <button className="bg-transparent hover:bg-primary text-link font-semibold hover:text-white py-1 px-3 border border-link hover:border-transparent rounded self-center" >
        {text}
      </button>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

This is weird... and maybe I'll find the reason why in the future.

Greetz,

Sascha